# Does $x^{-x}$ have rational solutions when $x$ is a non-integer rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

I want to know, given a rational number $x=\frac ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are distinct positive integers with $b\ne1$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, whether $x^{-x}$ can be rational as well.

What I achieved so far is as follows.

$$
\begin{align*}
x^{-x} &= \bigg(\frac{a}{b}\bigg)^{\big(-\frac{a}{b}\big)} \\
       &= \bigg(\frac{b}{a}\bigg)^{\big(\frac{a}{b}\big)} \\
       &= \frac{\sqrt[b]{b^a}}{\sqrt[b]{a^a}} \\
\end{align*}
$$

For this to be rational, either (i) both the numerator and the denominator must be rationals or (ii) they must share an irrational factor $r$ which will be canceled out by the division.

I can see that the first condition is unsatisfiable: As $a$ and $b$ have no common prime factors, both $\sqrt[b]{a}$ and $\sqrt[b]{b}$ must be rationals but $\sqrt[b]{b}$ cannot be a rational.

I cannot, however, prove or disprove whether the second condition is also unsatisfiable. If you can provide me a simple proof or point me to a complicated one, I would be grateful.

Comment: Why do you write $x^{-x}$ you could have asked $x^x$ only, it looks simple and is equivalent!

Comment: This would require b=k^b for some integer k.  That is easily shown to be impossible

Comment: If they have an irrational in common, that irrational is a root.  If your rise it to a and to be it becomes rational.  So it a root of a power that is a common factor of a and b.  But a and b is relatively prime.  So that's unsatisfactory.

Comment: all these are wrong, both the denominator and the numerator can be irrational, in that case t's difficult to tell whether the number is rational or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the contrary, let $x^{-x}$ be rational. Hence, it can be expressed as $\dfrac m n$, with $m$ being an integer and $n$ being a positive integer. Moreover, we can assume that $m$ and $n$ are co-prime.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x^{-x} &=& \dfrac m n \\
\left(\dfrac b a\right)^{a/b} &=& \dfrac m n \\
\dfrac{b^a}{a^a} &=& \dfrac{m^b}{n^b} \\
b^a n^b &=& a^a m^b \\
\end{array}$$

Let $p^k$ be a prime power factor of $b$ with maximum $k$. Then, $p^{ka}$ is a prime power factor of $b^a$ with maximum power. Since $b$ and $a$ are co-prime, the factorization of $a^a$ cannot contain $p$ at any power. Therefore, $p^{ka}$ must be a prime power factor of $m^b$.

Let $p^h$ be a prime power factor of $m$ with maximum $h$. Then, $p^{hb}$ is a prime power factor of $m^b$ with maximum power. Since $m$ and $n$ are co-prime, by the same argument, $p^{hb}$ must be a prime power factor of $b^a$.

Hence, $ka \le hb$ and $hb \le ka$, so $ka=hb$. Since $a$ and $b$ are co-prime, $k$ is divisible by $b$.

Since $p$ is arbitrary, this holds for any prime factor of $b$. In other words, if for any prime $p$, $p^k$ is a maximum prime power factor of $b$, then $k$ is divisible by $b$. This means that $b$ can be expressed as $c^b$ where $c$ is a positive integer.

We know that $c$ cannot be $1$, or else $b$ would be $1$. If $c$ is any larger, then we must have $c^b > b$. Therefore, it is impossible.

Comment: That was very easy to follow. Thank you very much. I'm a bit sad about the result though; I was hoping to find a rational solution.

Comment: @EserAygün It's simpler to reduce it to a basic result about mutual coprime powers - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $b>1$ and that $x^{-x}=\frac{\sqrt[b]{b^a}}{\sqrt[b]{a^a}}=\frac pq$ for some $p,q\in\Bbb Z$. Cross-multiplying and raising to the power of $b$ we get
$$a^ap^b=q^bb^a$$
Now consider factors of $a$ and $b$ in $q^b$ and $p^b$:

1. Because $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $a$ and $b$ occur at least $a$ times in $q^b$ and $p^b$ respectively.
2. To keep $p^b$ and $q^b$ perfect powers we need at least $-a\bmod b$ more factors of $a$ or $b$ on both sides.
3. To preserve the equality we need $-a\bmod b$ more factors each of $b$ in $q^b$ and $a$ in $p^b$ respectively.
4. To keep $p^b$ and $q^b$ perfect powers we need at least $+a\bmod b$ more factors of $a$ or $b$ on both sides.
5. To preserve the equality we need $+a\bmod b$ more factors each of $b$ in $p^b$ and $a$ in $q^b$ respectively.

Because $\pm a\not\equiv0\bmod b$, steps 2-5 are repeated infinitely, so $a^ap^b=q^bb^a$ is *never* satisfied if $b>1$. Since $b=1$ trivially yields a rational number, $x^{-x}$ is rational iff $x$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $\,x\!=\!\frac{a}b,\ (a,b)\!=\!1\,$ & $\,x^{x}\! = \frac{m}n,\ (m,n)\!=\!1\,$
then $\,\large \frac{a^a}{b^a} \!=\! \frac{m^b}{n^b}\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}b^a \!= n^{\color{#c00}b}$ (or $\,m^\color{#c00}{b}\,$ if $\,a<0),\,$  [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3067643/242) the coprime expts $\,(a,\color{#c00}b)\!=\!1\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}b\,$ too is a $\,\color{#c00}b$'th power, i.e. $\exists\:\! n\!\in\!\Bbb Z\!:\ b = n^b\, [\:\!\ge 2^b > b\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow]$